# Calculating screen texture coordinates in CG/HLSL

Tags: directx, shader, direct3d, hlsl

In OpenGL , sometimes when doing multi-pass rendering and post-processing I need to apply texels to the  primitive's assembly fragments which are part of full screen texture composition.That is usually the case when the current pass comes from FBO texture to which the screen quad had been rendered during previous pass.To achieve this I calculate objects UV coordinates  in SCREEN SPACE .In GLSL I calculate it like this:

```
     vec2 texelSize = 1.0 / vec2(textureSize(TEXTURE, 0));
 vec2 screenTexCoords = gl_FragCoord.xy * texelSize;
```

Now I am experimenting with Unity3D which uses [CG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cg_%28programming_language%29)/HLSL.The docs for these languages are poor.How can I calculate screen uv coordinates in CG/HLSL?

Comment: Have you even checked [the HLSL docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509561(v=vs.85).aspx)? They are significantly more comprehensive than GLSL, with a variety of very interesting related articles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate screen texcoords, you typically pass the screen resolution or reciprocal thereof (`res` or `rcpres`) to the shader, then use the texcoords from your fullscreen quad (assuming a range of `[0,1]`) modified by those.

**Edit:** Note that in many cases, you want both `res` and `rcpres` available. `res` is useful for calculating the current position (you wouldn't want to use `rcpres` for that, since it would then require division), but `rcpres` can be calculated once on the CPU and is useful for moving by a single texel (`(res * uv) + rcpres)` is one more texel from origin).

Something like:

```
float2 res; // contains the screen res, ie {640, 480}

void postEffect(in float2 uv : TEXCOORD, ...)
{
    float2 pos = uv * res; // pos now contains your current position
```

The logic being that the coords coming from the fs quad are `0,0` at texel `0,0` and `1,1` at texel `maxX,maxY`, so knowing the dimensions, you can just multiply.

You have to provide the value of `res` to each effect, however, which depends on your shader system (Unity3D may do it already).

Comment: Yes I see, but doing smth like this I am getting graphics (post process stuff) scaled if I resize the window.In OpenGL when using gl_FragCoord.xy  it doesn't happen.

Comment: If the window size changes, you need to update the variables passed to the shader. HLSL and Cg don't rely on magic variables the way GLSL does.

Comment: I do update those.When the frame re-sized I pass new screen size into the shader.