# Screen coordinates in fragment shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, cg

In a fragment shader like the below:

```
Shader "ColorReplacement" {

    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Greyscale (R) Alpha (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader {
        ZTest LEqual
        ZWrite On
        Pass {
            Name "ColorReplacement"
            CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
        #pragma target 3.0
                #include "UnityCG.cginc"


                struct v2f
                {
                    float4  pos : SV_POSITION;
                    float4  uv : TEXCOORD0;
                }; 

                v2f vert (appdata_tan v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                    o.uv = v.texcoord.xy;
                    return o;
                }

                sampler2D _MainTex;

                float4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
                {

                }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
    Fallback off
 }
```

Is there a way to know the coordinates of `i.uv` in the screen?

I'm totally new to shaders. The shader is applied to an object being drawn somewhere in the screen, the first pixel passed to `frag` possibly does not correspond to the first pixel of the screen (the viewport), is there a way to know the position of this pixel in screen coordinates?

---

**EDIT**
Yes, I want to obtain the fragment location on the screen.
Unity accepts vertex and fragment programs written in both Cg and HLSL. But I don't know how to convert this shader to HLSL.

The equivalent of gl_FragCoord in Cg is WPOS. I can run the following shader:

```
Shader "Custom/WindowCoordinates/Base" {
SubShader {
    Pass {
        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma target 3.0

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        float4 vert(appdata_base v) : POSITION {
            return mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
        }

        fixed4 frag(float4 sp:WPOS) : COLOR {
            return fixed4(sp.xy/_ScreenParams.xy,0.0,1.0);
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
}
```

That uses the screen position the way I want, but I'm a such noob that I can't even mix both shaders to get what I want: in my shader I'm trying to access `v2f.pos`, which is calculated the same way of `sp` in the shader above, but I get the error:

```
Program 'frag', variable/member "pos" has semantic "POSITION" which is not visible in this profile
```

If I change `pos` to be `WPOS` instead of `SV_POSITION` I get a similar error:

```
Program 'vert', variable/member "pos" has semantic "WPOS" which is not visible in this profile at line 35
```

Which is strange, since I'm using the same `target 3.0` of the above shader.

Comment: have you solved this ? :)

Comment: nope :( Ended up doing a workaround

Answer (score 0):

In GLSL fragment stage there's a built-in variable `gl_FragCoord` which carries the fragment pixel position within the viewport. If the viewport covers the whole screen, this is all you need. If the viewport covers only a subwindow of the screen, you'll have to pass the xy offset the viewport and add it to `gl_FragCoord.xy` to get the screen position. Now your shader code is not written in GLSL, but apparently Cg (with Unity extensions as it seems). But it should have some correspondence this this available.

Comment: That's not enough,he has to compute texel size to get correct screen coords.

Comment: I updated my question based on your answers, can you guys please take a look? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would suggest you to read some books or manuals on shaders,here is a simple solution

```
      vec2 texelSize = 1.0 / vec2(textureSize(yourTexSampler, 0));
  vec2 screenCoords = gl_FragCoord.xy * texelSize;
```

I don't remember how gl_FragCoord is called in Cg,so search in the docs.For the textureSize() - - substitute with width/height of the input texture.

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204364/calculating-screen-texture-coordinates-in-cg-hlsl) the pretty same question I asked some time ago.

Also take a look at [this](http://www.txutxi.com/?p=182).

Comment: I was under the impression that OP wanted to obtain the target fragment location on the screen. If it's about a texture's pixel, then yes, you have scale that as well.

Comment: Unity provides the texel size in `_MainTex_TexelSize.xy`.  Your `texelSize` computation is unnecessary.

Comment: Instead of mutiplying and dividing, just divide the frag coords by the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

[According to docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-BuiltinFunctions.html) there is a helper function - ComputeScreenPos.